# Can I Convert this utf8 Character?

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, html-parsing

I am using dom htm document function to scrape html and store it into MySQl. but I have notieced that for foriegn languages like chinese or japanese etc. some wierd charactors are stored in MySQL and I dont think any one can read this..,`é—¨æˆ·,æ–°é—»,ãƒ¼ã‚¿ãƒ«,æ¤œç´¢`

so my question is can I convert this back into original form by using any code??

if not I want to eliminate this from my table beacuse there is no use of it.how can I eliminate only these charactors from table??

Comment: What encoding are you using in the database?

Comment: MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Comment: MySQL connection collation: utf8_general_ci

Comment: @leon the default collation for tables is latin1_swedish. Can you confirm that your *tables* are UTF-8?

Comment: At some point, the input gets converted into (probably) a single-byte encoding like ISO-8859-1. Note that the database connection from within a script is usually ISO encoded and not UTF-8

Comment: if so how I need to do in future to avoide this??

Comment: @leon you need to find out where the problem is. Maybe sending a query `SET NAMES utf8;` after making the database connection helps

Comment: Perharps they are stored correctly and the problem is your output encoding.

Comment: This question should tell you all you need to know: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick if the input is actually UTF-8:

```
echo iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//IGNORE', 'news,é—¨æˆ·,æ–°é—»,portal,ç½‘æ˜“,163,china,é—¨æˆ·ç');
```

Answer (score -2):

Best way is to store this data after doing base64 encoding

1.) UNICODE TO UTF8

2.) UTF8 TO BASE64

Comment: Base64?? this isnt any encryption...I am not used any base64 encoding for data storage..