# How can I filter a non recognizable character from this?

Tags: php, regex

I have asked this before but cant find a response/answer to the same.

I do have tags like this..

```
news,é—¨æˆ·,æ–°é—»,portal,ç½‘æ˜“,163,china,é—¨æˆ·ç
```

I need to extract only `news,portal,163,china` from above. how can I do it in php??

Comment: It's worth noting that he's asking to remove some commas as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [can I convert this utf8 character??](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815714/can-i-convert-this-utf8-character)

Comment: @Vicario I believe you did not understand my question..I wasnt asked for removing commas...

Comment: Yet you accepted an answer that does so :-?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to keep only ascii alpha-numeric parts of this string, the following code will work:

```
$str = explode(',', $str);
$str = preg_grep('#^[[:alnum:]]+$#', $str);
$str = implode(',', $str);
```

This one too:

```
$str = preg_replace('#(^([^[:alnum:],]+,)+|,[^[:alnum:],]+)#', '', $str);
```

Which both return `news,portal,163,china`

Answer (score 2):

Replace anything that's not a letter or comma:

```
$sString = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9,]+/i', '', $sString);
$sString = preg_replace('/,{2,}/', ',', $sString);
```

Comment: This returns `,,news,,,portal,,,china,` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo str_replace(',,', ',', preg_replace('~[^a-zA-Z0-9,]~i', '', $searchString));
```

Comment: The ^ is misplaced, this returns the original string ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
s/([[:alnum:]\ ]+,?|) .*? ([[:alnum:]\ ]+,?|) /$1$2/xsg
```

or

```
s/[\x{80}-\x{1fffff}]+,?//g
```